# Is it necessary to check if auth.uid is not null if it is already checking for token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Currently

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.admin == true
```

Is it okay to do smth like this?

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary as trying to read the property `token` of `null` (if the user is not signed in) will just error out and reject the operation. You'll find many examples in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) that do not check `request.auth != null` explicitly before `request.auth.uid == '---'` or any role validation.

`request.auth.uid != null` is redundant as `token` will be defined only if the user is logged in and the role validation will pass if the user is an admin irrespective of the user ID.